# cpu hotplug - is there a system call to disable a cpu in linux?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, system-calls

Linux has '**cpu hotplug**' feature of enabling/disabling a cpu .

I want disable one of the computers' cpus from a C program , so my question is - how? is it possible ?

[Here](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/cpu-hotplug.txt) I found the following :

> Q: How do i logically offline a CPU?
>
> A: Do the following: **#echo 0 > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpuX/online**

Coudlnt find anything about system calls though in this document , so hopefully someone can shed some light about this, Thanks !

Comment: You have trouble with writing a single character to a file?

Comment: I dont have any feedback if it succedead that way..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no syscall for disabling a cpu in linux. What you found article is the only method. But you can rewrite the shell script to the below:

```
static void set_cpu_online(int cpu, int online)
{
        int fd;
        int ret;
        char path[256];

        snprintf(path, sizeof(path) - 1,
                 "/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu%d/online", cpu);

        fd = open(path, O_RDWR);
        assert(fd > 0);

        ret = write(fd, "0" + (online ? 1 : 0), 1);
        assert(ret == 1);
}
```